# How to mock the optional ResponseEntity code below for code coverage. Could someone please assist?

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito, junit5, response-entity

public ResponseEntity<Optional> getData(@RequestBody RequestModel requestModel) {
try {
List mango = new ArrayList();

```
        mangoRepository.findByMangoTag(
                requestModel.getMangoTag(),
                requestModel.getMangoProduct(),
                requestModel.getSellerType()).forEach(mango::add);

        Optional<Mango> res = mango.stream().findFirst();
        if (!res.isPresent()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(res, HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
```

Comment: Please, show your test code. Also, what exactly is the problem? Is it mocking the repository?

Comment: Hi Jonasz, Thanks for reaching out. I don't have any idea mocking methods with response entity. I tried and getting error with stubbing. Please help

Comment: Attach your code and the error you are getting with a stacktrace. You'd like to test the endpoint of your controller whlie mocking the repository, correct?

Comment: Can you please add the repository method 'findByMangoTag'